# Get a CSS position transition not to react on window zooming

Tags: javascript, css, transition, slide, zooming

I have a CSS3 position transition that makes a dive slide from one side to another when called by a JavaScript function (the function changes the value of style element "left"). This works great, but the CSS-transition also reacts to when a window is zoomed or resized, causing the div to appear in a faulty position for a second, before it transitions back to place.

Is there any way to only make it react only to my function, or do I have to do it the old fashion way, making a JavaScript transition?

**Edit:** You can find my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/PURFp/

Comment: `left` shouldn't change when you zoom or resize the browser, can you post your css/js/html or a link?

Comment: Of course! Here you go! http://jsfiddle.net/PURFp/
(I used the -webkit- prefix so that it works in chrome, witch I am currently on. I know it is not the standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the transition property right before you start the animation and remove it after the animation has ended. Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PURFp/2/.